# Getting Image Resource from 'RecyclerView'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making an app which have  recycler view for displaying hotels and restaurants.
Which uses onClickListener on the container.

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item,viewGroup,false);
        final myViewHolder viewHolder = new myViewHolder(v);
        viewHolder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,hotel_main.class);
                intent.putExtra("hotel_name_title",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getHotelName());
                intent.putExtra("hotel_des_location",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDeslocation());
                intent.putExtra("hotel_background_img",mData.get(i).getBackground());


                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Here the background of the hotel is an image resource and i want to display this on to the second page where it is Intent to go. But it does not display any image. This is the code in the hotel_main activity.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hotel_main);

        //Receive data

        String title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hotel_name_title");
        String location = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hotel_des_location");
        String background = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hotel_background_img");



        //init views
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsingtoolbar_id);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);

        TextView tv_title = findViewById(R.id.hotelmain_title_page);
        TextView tv_location = findViewById(R.id.hotelmain_card_nb_des);
        ImageView iv_background = findViewById(R.id.hotelmain_card_background);

        //setting values to each view
        tv_title.setText(title);
        tv_location.setText(location);

        Glide.with(this).load(background).into(iv_background);

       }
    }
```

Here the Image is displayed blank can anyone help?

Comment: Check the value of `background` in `hotel_main` activity using debugger

Comment: how can me do that, should i be using log for this ?

Comment: Put a log after you get the `background`value from intent. `Log.d("BACKGROUND", background)`

Comment: `D/ADebugTag: Value: null ` This is what i got in the debugger.

Comment: Then there is nothing to load, that's why you see blank. Your `getBackground()` is returning null in `onCreateViewHolder`. Please put your whole adapter code in the question

Comment: Thank you @AyushKhare , it was a simple solve. It is solved thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved My Own answer by changing the code from

```
String background = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hotel_background_img");
```

to

```
int background = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("hotel_background_img");
```

as it was returning null in log, thank you guys

Comment: so `hotel_background_img` was an image from resource folder but not a string url ?

Comment: Yes, i figured that one when i saw the 'RecyclerView' Adapter Code using `myViewHolder.background_img.setImageResource(mData.get(i).getBackground());` inside the `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 1):

Check background is null or not , background is null then image not load ,so check  background variable value.

Comment: I used this code

               `Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + background);`

and got this Answer, what should i do.

`D/ADebugTag: Value: null`